# Multiple providers in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I am using multiple users providers in my project.

My security.yml looks like this :

```
security:
  ...
  firewalls:
    usertype1:
       pattern: ^/root/usertype1_area
       provider: type1_provider
    usertype2
       pattern: ^/root
       provider: type2_provider
  ...
```

Everything is working fine and I can't login with wrong user types at the right pattern, except that I noticed that if I throw an exception in one of my providers, say `type1_provider` , and try to log in with the `/root/login` path (which should use only `type2_provider`), Symfony is going through `type1_provider` as well as `type2_provider`, and I get an exception.

The same is also true with `/root/usertype1_area/login` when I throw at `type2_provider`.

This is a problem to me because I want to be able to access type2 login when the `type1_provider` is shut down.

Any guesses ? Is this normal behavior ?

**EDIT :** ***As pointed out by Alexander Keil, it was not clear in my question what I was trying to do***

One of my providers relies on a 3d party service, and I want it to throw when this service is down, but I still want to be able to access the other login, which is not supposed to rely on the provider that is throwing. Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "supportsClass" in your provider. Return false if the current user class does not support the loaded provider. See Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already implemented UserProviderInterface correctly in my both providers, my question is, why does Symfony need to use a provider when another is explicitely supplied in security.yml ?

Comment: Your question was why you get an exception. With implementation of supportsClass this should be avoided. I don't know why symfony is going through all providers, it shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear, the exception is intentionnal when one of my providers is down. I will edit my question in a few.